# React Native how to design this button?

Tags: android, ios, css, react-native

I need help in designing this button in react-native. Please help me?

[image: Button]]

Comment: My friend, you have to add your code and explain your problem

Answer (score 0):

I will help you out for this problem. but please know the procedures to ask a question. There should be some initial work and try out before asking a question. As I knew that you are a new contributor and i also did mistakes like this. So I am helping you.

You can achieve this by referring the following code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
          <View style={styles.btnLabelStyle}>
            <Text>adfadafd</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.leftIcon} >
            <Text style ={{color : '#0a6df0', fontSize:25, fontWeight:'bold'}}>+</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.rightIcon}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{'>'}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    padding: 8,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  btnContainer: {
    width: '70%',
    height: 40,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingRight: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderColor:'green',
    borderWidth:1,
  },
  leftIcon: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    left: -10,
    borderColor:'#0a6df0',
    borderWidth:1,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  rightIcon: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    position: 'absolute',
    right: -9,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  btnLabelStyle:{
    marginLeft:40, //lefticon width
    marginRight:20, // right icon width
  }
});
```

[image]

You can also use this expo snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@sivakumar00/button-material)